# JavaEE Servlet Specification: Container vs. Context vs. Servlet vs. Config

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have been working with Spring web applications and servlets for some time now but sometimes I still have difficulties to keep track of how everything comes together.

With respect to servlets and servlet containers such as Tomcat there are usually the following concepts that are frequently being used:

- Container (as in Tomcat being a container for)
- Context (as implemented by ServletContext interface)
- Config  (as implemented by ServletConfig interface)
- Servlet (as for example DispatcherServlet in Spring)

What I am looking for is an *info graphic* or some other kind of graphic/diagram that gives a **good visual overview** of how these concepts are used to together. Something that makes a good reference and that I can print out and hang next to my computer.

What such a graphic should preferably show is:

- How concepts such as the servlet context, servlet config and the servlets themselves are related in a container.
- How context initialization works, e.g. starting with `ServletContainerInitializer` and then all the way to something like `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServlet` and friends.

**Note:** I am not asking for explanations of these concepts. I can read about that in the reference documentation and other specification documents. I am specifically asking about graphics and visualizations that make it easier to grasp the big picture and which can be used as a reference.

P.S: It does not necessary have to be all in a single graphic, one for the Servlet specification and or tomcat and another one for Spring is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

I've found graphics in a book [Head First Servlets](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch05s10.html) very informative.

[image]